# Как для enum можно присвоить одинаковые значения?

Tags: c#, enum

Как для `enum` можно присвоить одинаковые значения `int` не делая так:

```
public enum CardName
{
    Ace = 11,
    King = 10,
    Queen = 10,
    Jack = 10,
    Ten = 10,
    Nine = 9,
    Eight = 8,
    Seven = 7,
    Six = 6,
    Five = 5,
    Four = 4,
    Three = 3,
    Two = 2
};
```

Думал сначала сделать через `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, но мне показалось что идея так себе, что посоветуете?

Comment: [Non-unique enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8043127/2881286)

Comment: А зачем вам как-то по другому? Нормальный же способ

Comment: А я бы сделал словарь.

Comment: попробуй сделать разные значения, и добавить метод который для "неправильно пронумерованных" выдавал бы нужные значения

Comment: Можно ещё `Ten = 10, King = Ten, Queen = Ten, Jack = Ten`, но не вижу смысла. @АндрейNOP прав — приведённый код и так понятен.